# Adding - button on Image ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to add button on Image. I am showing image from `django database in javascript (HTML)`.

I am trying to add clickable button on Image.

views.py

```
def user_stories(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

template.html

```
    <script>
        var blogposts = new BlogPost('blogposts', {
            blogposts: [
                // {% for post in posts %}
                BlogPost.buildTimelineItem(
                    '{{ post }}',
                    '{{ user.profile.file.url }}',
                    '{{ post.user }}',
                    '{{post.id}}',
                    timestamp(),
                    [
                        [
                            '{{post.id }}-1',
                            'photo',
                            3,
                            
                            '{{ post.image.url }}',                   
                            '',
                            false,
                            false,
                            timestamp(),
                        ],
                    ]
                ),
                // {% endfor %}
            ],
        });
    </script>
```

```
  BlogPostJS.buildTimelineItem = (id, photo, name, link, lastUpdated, items) => {
    const timelineItem = {
      id,
      photo,
      name,
      link,
      lastUpdated,
      items: []
    };

    each(items, (itemIndex, itemArgs) => {
      timelineItem.items.push(BlogPostJS.buildBlogPostItem.apply(BlogPostJS, itemArgs));
    });

    return timelineItem;
  };
```

`{{ post.image.url }}` is showing image, AND i am trying to add on it.

- I also tried by adding :- `'{{ post.image.url }}<button type='submit' </button>'`, BUT it is not showing on image.

I have no idea , how can i add button on image.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to have a button overlaying the image OR the button should be an image?

Comment: @Sid, Yes i want a small clickable button on `image`

Comment: Please add the code where you are trying to Add Image in HTML

Comment: I have mentioned in question that `Image is displaying through '{{ post.image.url }}'` in <script> tag.

Comment: This is more of a css question, check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp

Comment: I also tried this before ( provided link ) . as it mentioned i add button. BUT it didn't worked for me.

Comment: @Sid, BUT how can do it in `javascript image` ?

Comment: Hi, can you add link to your plugin which you are using in js code ?

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in BlogPost.buildTimelineItem you either need to modify it to include the button, or postprocess the result and add the button manually once the post is rendered. What you tried passes an invalid url because the function accepts image url which I suppose is rendered into an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Sir, I have updated the question, Can you tell me, How can i do it ?

Comment: add the html that the BlogPost.buildTimelineItem generates, what does timelineItem contain? is it an html or a js object?

Comment: `timelineItem` is a `JS` object that contain `image` and `some other links and urls`

Comment: if it contains html, you can add the button there, but unless you update your post with the contents I can't be more specific